# Does 'hook up' imply a superficial relationship?

Tags: connotation, phrase-meaning, synonyms

I am a non-native speaker.

I would like to express that something happened two years after a character has formed a relationship with a loved one. This is what I wrote:

> Two years after I hooked up with Sarah, we went to Paris.

I was suddenly unsure about the phrasing, though, and wonder if this would imply a superficial, mere sexual relationship rather than a love affair.

If so, are there more appropriate alternatives to describe such a relationship?

Comment: Casual, but not necessarily superficial.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I think so. Not necessarily just sexual, but certainly an informal relationship.

Why not just use the words you use here? "Two years after the start of my relationship with Sarah"

Comment: I actually thought about doing so, but it sounds a little to formal for me. I would like to retain a laid-back writing style

Comment: Yes, on first mention, one ought to describe the relationship more precisely. Once the reader is aware of what is going on, one can be more informal.

Comment: As OP uses the term, *hooked up* works well, the term doesn't address the quality or quantity of the relationship, but is only a reference to its *initiation* point, as Clare puts it, *the start*, *hooked up* is merely a casual, hip manner of speaking which seems to meet the OP's desire for a *laid-back* style of expression.

Comment: If you want to suggest a more permanent relationship but keep the phrasing informal, you could use "got together" — *Two years after Sarah and I got together, we went to Paris*

Comment: @Sprottenwels great pun though... *laid-back*. As for me I would say it’s only in more recent time the sexual only meaning. I haven’t checked etymology but I suspect it is although maybe it was for a time the casual sex meaning beforehand. I have however in recent years including this year heard it in the non sexual way too.